# ts(2454) Variable 'value' is used before being assigned

Tags: typescript

I get the typescript compile time error "Variable 'value' is used before being assigned ts(2454)" for the following code (in strict mode):

```
class Box<T> {
    constructor(private value: T) {
    }

    map<U>(f: (val: T) => U): Box<U> {
        return new Box<U>(f(this.value));
    }

    tap(f: (val: T) => unknown): void {
        f(this.value);
    }
}

function getValue<T>(box: Box<T>): T {
    let value: T;
    box.tap((val: T) => value = val);
    return value;
}

const multiplyByTwo = (value: number) => value * 2;
const box = new Box<number>(55).map(multiplyByTwo);
const val = getValue(box);
console.log(val);
```

The error is generated for the line "return value" of the function getValue.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD2APAPAFQHzQN4Chr+mHgDsIAXAJwFdgz4KAKABwoEsA3MMgU2k5CrcAXNFQBKbHgIBfHFPwBbME2QBVdAwBmIhvxHjoAXkyqxIhCnWSCN6BW5kqFYtGLcA7nCRqNmhmQALVggAOn5BMTEAbnloWViyZS0dPVEJY2gqYgBrYnh3YjM+eFYAE2tbfD9A4LCwAW5o2Nl4zSzaVhJoAHMHADV6wTQNACMkc28MItQK-BAHPkHhURibMcQQxKYGXXr9dMxw3kNFkCabe0dnU8EY+KJSMmgFKhAyViYQAE9YL9R3eBGaC7BoiYhUBQjbgUA43XgAKmgACYYg9yNB1kC3J4LMhwZDoRoAKxEsQhJTbF5vD7fX7-eBNNFPfhA3pkAYNBjrRkkCDweYhEDwbog6JAA)

Comment: Hi, it might help if you provide hints to what your are trying to achieve. In the current code, you know more than the compiler hence the error. I believe the code needs to be refactored to not throw an error.

Comment: Hi, the code snippet is a simplified version of a code where i try to wrap an either  ramda-fantay monad in order to extend it via the decorator pattern. In particular i added a getValue() method that return the left/right value encapsulated by the monad.

Comment: The compiler is right. It can see that the variable `value` is used by the closure passed to `box.tap()` but it cannot know what does `box.tap()` with the closure. When the code is executed, `getValue()` can receive as `box` an instance of a class that extends `Box` and implements `Box.tap()` in a different way.

Answer (score 4):

Try it `return value!`.

**Non-null Assertion**

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33524863)

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the error presented. If the error were "this value may be undefined" then using a non-null assertion would tell TypeScript that it will be defined, but the error of "used before declaration" isn't fixed by a non-null assertion

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an elegant solution. I only marked the line with a @ts-ignore comment.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not know that the `tap` callback is actually going to be executed before the `return value` line, so for all it knows the variable still has its initial value `undefined` (which is not a `T`).

The proper (and elegant) solution is not to abuse a helper function like `tap` to access the value, but put a proper method for that in the class itself:

```
class Box<T> {
    constructor(private value: T) {
    }

    map<U>(f: (val: T) => U): Box<U> {
        return new Box<U>(f(this.value));
    }

    getValue(): T {
        return this.value;
    }

    tap(f: (val: T) => unknown): Box<T> {
        f(this.getValue());
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but Box is some third party api that i can't change.

Comment: @sageagat you should have been more explicit about that in your question. Can you link the docs of that `Box` API? Presumably it has a much better way to access the value than `tap`.

Comment: sorry for that. As i said to @sunknudsen the real code is about ramda-fantasy either monad [link](https://github.com/ramda/ramda-fantasy/blob/master/docs/Either.md). I wrapped it inside a decorator class in order to extend its functionnality. Inside the decorator i have a getValue method that tries to access the value of the monad via its either method.

Comment: @sageagat You might want to edit your question to show your real code. Is the `Box` in your snippet the `Either` class or the custom decorator class? Also, the `either` method has a very different signature than `tap`, so I'm not sure what you're doing. You definitely should not need to assign a mutable `value` in a closure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the compiler is not told what the callback does (`(val: T) => unknown` is not aware of `value = val` without running the code) so it doesn’t know `value` is set.